# Help "reversing" a formula "x = 12 - 2y"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm breaking my head over "reversing" a formula.
I have a constant set of input numbers (y) and two constant sets of 3 output numbers (x).

Formula that defines first relation is simple: x = 12 - 2y

```
x <= y
-set 1-
2 <= 5
4 <= 4
6 <= 3
-set 2-
8 <= 2
10 <= 1
12 <= 0
```

What I fail to figure out is how to "reverse" the formula so that "mirrored" input would produce same values.
The catch is "reversed" set is not linear. It's in a way parabolical if you look at numbers as an order.

I need to get exact "x" with defined "y" from 0 to 5.

x = ???

```
x <= y
-set 1-
8 <= 5
10 <= 4
12 <= 3
-set 2-
2 <= 2
4 <= 1
6 <= 0
```

To demonstrate how mirrored input expected to produce same values.

Input:

```
5 2 | 2 5
4 1 | 1 4
3 0 | 0 3
```

Output:

```
2 8  | 2 8
4 10 | 4 10
6 12 | 6 12
```

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Do you mean $x = 12 - 2y$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: If you only have to have a way to convert the integers $0$ through $5$ into (possibly) different integers then you can just use a lookup table. Otherwise what you have looks like a conditional formula where you choose a linear formula depending on whether your input is greater than $2.$ There are also any number of complicated ways of making the numbers come out this way.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you! I updated notation.

Comment: @DavidK I had it described in two formulas: "x = 6 - 2y" for y <= 2 and "x = 6 + (6 - y)*2" for y > 2. I could also have a matrix considering numbers are deterministic. But there is no fun in this. I felt there is a solution but could not figure it out. And I was just amazed with actual answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a sequence that follows your six output values in order $(6,4,2,12,10,8)$. We note they are double of $(3,2,1,6,5,4)$, which conveniently is the start into a known sequence with its OEIS entry under URL: https://oeis.org/A113655

A113655 is called the "Invert blocks of three in the sequence of natural numbers" and starts like this:
3,2,1,6,5,4,9,8,7,...
This is useful then. In fact, (one of) A113655's formulation is

$ a(n)=(2+n)-2\cdot[(n+2)\mod3]$

where $n$ is in range of $(1,\infty$). Your $y$ however is in range $(0,5)$, so we modify the formula to compensate for halfed values by multiplying by 2 and for our y shifted from $1$ to $0$ by increasing both shifts by 1. We obtain for your desired expression of $x$:

$x=2\cdot[(3+y)-2\cdot[(y+3)\mod3]]$

Comment: OMFG! You're amazing! Math is amazing! That is soooo coooool!

Comment: Btw. Did you know there are sequences of numbers in bible?! :) I found it peculiar and interesting but information and sets are scarce and not complete.

Comment: Glad to hear it works for you. YW. Please provide a link to what you mean by seq. in bible.

Comment: I will get back with this later after checking the book I have. Turns out there are a ton of revisions to look it up online. From top of my head I think it was somewhere in Genesis when descendants were described. Sequence was something like: numbers that appear random - 65 - 34 - 65 - 32 - 65 - 30 - numbers that appear random.

Comment: Heya. I got the book. Though I don't know which revision it is. It only says "Trinitarian Bible Society".
Here are the number extracts (I can send you pictures but it's Russian lol).
It's from "Old Testament, First book of Moses". I'm not sure how this part is called in English. It's right before "Exodus".

It's kinda confusing because there numbers are split into 3 subsets: "total years", "years when child was born", "years after the child was born".

Comment: Chapter 11
Sim 100 -> Arfaksad -> 500 (or 600) |
Arfaksad 35 -> Sala -> 403 (or 438) |
Sala 30 -> Ever -> 400 (or 430) |
Ever 34 -> Falek -> 430 (or 464) |
Falek 30 -> Ragav -> 209 (or 239) |
Ragav 32 -> Seruh -> 207 (or 239) |
Seruh 30 -> Nahor -> 200 (or 230) |
Nahor 29 -> Farra -> 119 (or 148) |
I can theoretically continue left sequence: ... 30 - 29 - 30 - 25 - 30 - 20
Right sequence has no sense for me.

P.S.:
Ow. Poopy. No formatting here. I will split lines with |

Comment: Chapter 5
Another example where numbers jump between two subsets:
800 (912) -> 90 -> 815 (905) -> 70 -> 815 (910) -> 65